# How to combine sections of text, line by line

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++

Is there a way (in Microsoft Office, Notepad++, etc), to combine multiple sections of text, line by line, so, for example, my text would changes from this:

```
section 1, line 1
section 1, line 2
section 1, line 3
section 1, line 4

section 2, line 1
section 2, line 2
section 2, line 3
section 2, line 4

section 3, line 1
section 3, line 2
section 3, line 3
section 3, line 4
```

-to -

```
section 1, line 1
section 2, line 1
section 3, line 1

section 1, line 2
section 2, line 2
section 3, line 2

section 1, line 3
section 2, line 3
section 3, line 3

section 1, line 4
section 2, line 4
section 3, line 4
```

`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort in a graduatin pattern as you have shown then you can.

```
Edit > Line Operations > Sort Lines in Ascending / Descending Order
```

However if your need is to merge you can follow the suggestions found here.

> [Can I use Notepad++ to selectivelly merge two text files?](https://superuser.com/questions/361116/can-i-use-notepad-to-selectivelly-merge-two-text-files)