# Merging two notepad++ files?

Tags: notepad++

I have two notepad++ files.
The first has the following text:

```
1-Blue
2-Red
3-Black

4-Yellow 
5-Pink
```

In the second file, i have the following text:

```
Eyes
Arms
Head

Car
Pen
```

i want to merge the two files in a way such that each line in the second file goes below the corresponding line in the first file. so the answer should be:

```
1-Blue
Eyes
2-Red
Arms
3-Black
Head

4-Yellow
Car
5-Pink
Pen
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer here: [Can I use Notepad++ to selectivelly merge two text files?](https://superuser.com/questions/361116/can-i-use-notepad-to-selectivelly-merge-two-text-files)

references this stackoverflow question, ["combining-files-in-notepad++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971420/combining-files-in-notepad)

[The top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4066116/3066295) says to install a Python script plugin from http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/, and provides this sample script to "combines all currently opened files into a single file":

```
console.show()
console.clear()
files = notepad.getFiles()
notepad.new()
newfile = notepad.getCurrentFilename()
for i in range(len(files) - 1):
    console.write("Copying text from %s\n" % files[i][0])
    notepad.activateFile(files[i][0])
    text = editor.getText()
    notepad.activateFile(newfile)
    editor.appendText(text)
    editor.appendText("\n")
console.write("Combine Files operation complete.")
```

Here is another stackoverflow question: ["merge-two-files-in-notepad++"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873857/merge-two-files-in-notepad)

Comment: Welcome to the site. It is awesome that you are jumping in to help answer questions. Bit of advice; it is better to explain the answer and use the links as a reference because links can stop working, which would leave your answer useless.

Comment: (the links indicate that this is a duplicate while also trying to help)