# Merging Multiple Files Line by line Notepad++ Python?

Tags: notepad++, python

I have Multiple Text files, I would like to create a playlist from & need to combine them in sequential order line by line. I'm aware of a sample Python script to combine files but have no idea how to modify script to do the following. It would be appreciated if someone could provide a working script.

## Input:

**Text_A File**

```
Video_A1
Video_A2
Video_A3
```

**Text_B File**

```
Video_B1
Video_B2
Video_B3
```

**Text_C File**

```
Video_C1
Video_C2
Video_C3
```

## Output:

```
Video_A1
Video_B1 
Video_C1
Video_A2
Video_B2
Video_C2
Video_A3
Video_B3
Video_C3
```

Comment: If you hover on the python tag, you'll see that script questions are on topic on Stack Overflow rather than here.  But even SO is not a "write me a script" site.  People will help you solve a specific issue if you try to do it yourself and document what you're doing and the problem encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Python script. You just need to change the first 3 lines. `newline` should be set to "\n" on Linux and "\r\n" on Windows. `files` is the list of input files and `outfile` is the name of the output file.

```
newline = "\r\n"
files = ["A.txt", "B.txt", "C.txt"]
outfile = "Output.txt"

for i in range(0, len(files)):
  files[i] = open(files[i], "rU")

with open(outfile, "w") as out:
  while True:
    finished = True
    for f in files:
      line = f.readline()
      if line != "":
        finished = False
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        out.write(line + newline)
    if finished:
      break
```

Here is another script that you can use from within Notepad++ if you have the PythonScript plugin installed

```
newline = "\r\n"

files = []
for (name, id, idx, view) in notepad.getFiles():
  if view != 0:
    continue
  notepad.activateBufferID(id)
  files.append(editor.getText().splitlines())

notepad.new()

lineNr = 0
while True:
  lines = ""
  for file in files:
    if len(file) > lineNr: lines += file[lineNr] + newline
  if(len(lines) > 0): editor.appendText(lines)
  else: break
  lineNr += 1
```

Comment: Nice script, Unfortunately this requires full file path. The above was an example I need to be able to merge multiple playlist I have open in notepad++ & preferably output to a new tab. I tried using files = notepad.getFiles() & some other code from a combine script, but was only able to C:\Output.txt an empty file.

Comment: @joeatari I have posted something on [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/EguuSGs0) you might be interested in. It riffs off this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971420/combining-files-in-notepad) which is [duplicated on SuperUser here](https://superuser.com/questions/1262792/merging-two-notepad-files). My code for Python and Notepad++ probably isn't as tidy or well put together as SpiderPig's, but after a bit of testing, I believe it should (basically) do what you want.

Comment: Anaksunaman's script is good but there are a few things I would do differently to improve the reliability of the script. So I added another solution to my answer.

Comment: That's the bee's knees right there, SpiderPig. I can't speak for joeatari, but from my end, thanks for sharing. =)